# How to reach socket.io clients from API routes

Tags: node.js, express, socket.io

I have x number of clients connected.

If something happens in my API, meaning that if I received data from 3 parts, how do I push that out to specific clients?

```
var socketio = require('socket.io');
exports.socketServer = function (app, server) {
  var clients = [];
  var io = socketio.listen(server);
  io.sockets.on('connection', function (socket) {

  });
});
```

Example API/callback (this is in a another file)

```
exports.callback = function(req, res){
    //how do reach my socket.io and my clients from here
};
```

Comment: Do you need to target specific clients, or do you just want to send a message to all of them?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can pass the io around. Here's one way, In the API/callback file

```
var io;

var initializeSocket = function (socket) {
    io = socket;
}

var callback = function (req, res) {
    // your code here and which will have a reference to io object
}

module.exports = {callback: callback, initializeSocket: initializeSocket};
```

Before that you have to call the initializeSocket method of that Api/callback module with io object from here,

```
var socketio = require('socket.io');
var Api = require(./location_to_your_Api_callback_file);

exports.socketServer = function (app, server) {
  var clients = [];
  var io = socketio.listen(server);
  Api.initilizeSocket(io);
  io.sockets.on('connection', function (socket) {

  });
});
```